# MySQL case sensitive insert

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, case-sensitive

I have created a database with case sensitive character set:

```
Create database Grupo88 character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE Grupo88.Usuarios(
    nombreUsuario varchar(30) primary key,
    clave varchar(120) not null);

INSERT INTO usuarios(nombreUsuario,clave)
       VALUES('guy','pass');
INSERT INTO usuario(nombreUsuario, clave)
       VALUES('Guy', 'password');
```

The first `insert` goes well, but the second one says that the value "Guy" already exists. Setting my database to be case sensitive is not enough? How can I do to allow case sensitive inserts?

EDIT: Apparently the problem was in the stored procedure that was inserting into the table 'usuarios'. Scripts posted here work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `binary` keyword when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Grupo88.Usuarios (
    nombreUsuario varchar(30) binary primary key,
    clave varchar(120) not null
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5116e/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use `BINARY` in creating the table

```
mysql>     CREATE TABLE Grupo88.Usuarios
    ->     (
    ->         nombreUsuario varchar(30) BINARY,
    ->         clave varchar(120) not null);
    ->     );
```